# Adding custom fields to auth_user table in Django

Tags: django

Currently I created another class/table called `MyAppUser` with my custom columns (such as address and phone number) that has a foreign key to Django's authentication `User`.

Something like this

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyAppUser( models.Model ) :
    def __unicode__( self ) :
       return self.user.username

    user    = models.ForeignKey( User )
    comment = models.TextField( blank = True )
    phone   = models.CharField( max_length = 135, blank = True )
```

Is the above method a good practice? Or should I try to modify the `auth_user` directly? And if so, how would I do that?

Bonus question: Is there a way to have both my custom table to be called `User` as well? I thought about trying `from django.contrib.auth import models`, then calling `models.User`, but then I think that would conflict with `django.db.models` as well. Maybe I need to try `from django.contrib.auth.models import User as AuthUser`? Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Django provides built-in support for extending the user with your own properties, called [User Profiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).

Comment: The django doc has updated. So the link to 'User Profiles' is https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users

Comment: The link returns 502 :(

Comment: Note that in the link, they use `user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)`, which will throw a django warning.  You should use `user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=...)` instead

Comment: I removed the link that recommended using a `ForeignKey` and updated the link to point to the current method of doing this

Answer (score 3):

That is generally the method I prefer, I don't like to touch the Django user just to be safe.  This way you know you aren't going to conflict with anything in the user model, and it makes it clear which code is framework code and which is your code.

I normally don't call it `MyAppUser` but more usually, something like `UserSettings`.  I don't want my user related classes to be confused as replacements for the `User` object, but simply provide more information.

Generally in apps you will have foreign keys to `User` all over the place, so I still use Django `User` class for all those as well. I find it keep things cleaner.

I have tried to subclass `User` and found it didn't give me much, and ended up confusing things, more than they needed to be.