# Usertype models in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm being confused on where table how I insert my usertypes, I'm just a beginner on Django but surely Im been reading documentation in Django but I can't understand this one , The case is when I register new user there's must be choice what usertype should specify with this user either an admin or etc. but the problem is I think there is no relationship table from authuser even I create another table.slight similar to this problem resources [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671266/adding-custom-fields-to-auth-user-table-in-django). For now I'm been thinking to create custom usertype field in authuser table, but when migrate it didn't show updated fields and also like this issue some people or user didn't touch or add any field in authuser table [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9671375/14517031) it is possible to insert usertype in auth_permission or other default table? Im just really confused of where table I can add my usertype that have a relationship to authuser. Is there any know or explain about this, thanks

> Models

```
class AuthUser(models.Model):
  password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
  last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
  is_superuser = models.IntegerField()
  username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
  email = models.CharField(max_length=254)
  is_staff = models.IntegerField()
  is_active = models.IntegerField()
  date_joined = models.DateTimeField()

  usertype_id = usertype = models.OneToOneField(usertypes,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True) 
  () //this is what i want to add

  class Meta:
     managed = False
     db_table = 'auth_user'

class usertypes(models.Model):
  usertype = models.CharField(max_length=264)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=264)
  status = models.CharField(max_length=264)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways how to do it. The way I recommned is to extend the existing user model.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserType(models.Model):
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=264)

class AppUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.ForeignKey(UserType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This will create 2 extra tables.

1. user_type where you will have UserTypes that you probably want to fill and
2. app_user where will be stored reference on django user record and its type

However, I think you should have a good reason why you do this. Django allows you to group users into the user groups, what should be exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response  can you explain more about AppUser class? So do I need to add it in my models? the User you put in AppUser means it is  connected to authuser?relational?  And also Yes I used user groups to used in user roles permissions but it conflicts if I use this in static usertype since my purpose in groups is multiple usertype for permission. All i want is when the user login it specify or pop up what usertype he/she is.